# Copy symlink to another location with ansible?

Tags: copy, symlink, ansible

I have my symlink and want to create new symlink, that points to the same location that first symlink points. I know I can use `cp -d /path/to/symlink /new/path/to/symlink`. But how do it with ansible module?

I was trying `copy: src=/path/to/symlink dest=/new/path/to/symlink follow=yes` but it makes a copy of symlink instead create new symlink. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two option here.

1) Create New Symlink using [file](http://docs.ansible.com/file_module.html#file-sets-attributes-of-files) module.

```
- name: Create symlink
  file: src=/path/to/symlink  dest=/new/path/to/symlink state=link
```

2) Run your working command to copy symlink using [shell](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html#shell-execute-commands-in-nodes) it will do the same.

```
- name: Create symlink
  shell: cp -d /path/to/symlink /new/path/to/symlink
```

Comment: First answer is not correct for me, because new symlink points to old symlink, while I want that new symlink will point to old symlink location. Eg: **/my/project/location** is my project directory, **/path/to/symlink** points to **/my/project/location** and **/new/path/to/symlink** points also to **/my/project/location**. Sectond anwer is correct.